# Doctrine relationships

Tags: doctrine, models, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables. A users table and a profile table. The profile table has a foreign key of users_id. The models for the tables are set up with one to one relationships. When I try and save some data I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'users_id' cannot be null' in
```

If I just save data to the users table then I know that it is auto_incrementing and generating a new id value. However, for some reason when I try and link the tables together or call $users->id then it returns a value of NULL.

Here is my code:

```
$u = new Users();
// Users table.
        $u->username   = $username;
        $u->password   = $password;
        $u->email      = $email;
        $u->groups_id   = $group_id;
        $u->ip_address = $ip_address;
        $u->last_login = now();
        $u->active     = 1;

    if ($this->store_salt)
    {
        $u->salt = $salt;
    }
    $u->save();

    // Profile table.
    $p = new Profile(); 
    $p->first = $additional_data['first'];
    $p->last = $additional_data['last'];
    $p->role = $additional_data['role'];
    $p->Users = $u;
    $p->save(); return;
```

Here are the models:

```
 /**
 * BaseUsers
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
```

> - - @property integer $id
>   - @property string $username
>   - @property string $password
>   - @property string $ip_address
>   - @property date $created_at
>   - @property date $updated_at
>   - @property string $salt
>   - @property string $email
>   - @property string $activation_code
>   - @property string $forgotten_password_code
>   - @property string $remember_code
>   - @property integer $last_login
>   - @property integer $active
>   - @property integer $groups_id
>   - @property Groups $Groups
>   - - @package    ##PACKAGE##
>   - @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
>   - @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
>   - @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 6401 2009-09-24 16:12:04Z guilhermeblanco $
>       */

```
 abstract class BaseUsers extends Doctrine_Record
 {
     public function setTableDefinition()
     {
    $this->actAs("Timestampable");
    $this->setTableName('users');
    $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'unsigned' => 0,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('username', 'string', 45, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 45,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 45, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 45,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('ip_address', 'string', 16, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 16,
         'fixed' => true,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'date', null, array(
         'type' => 'date',
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'date', null, array(
         'type' => 'date',
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('salt', 'string', 40, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 40,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('email', 'string', 40, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 40,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('activation_code', 'string', 40, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 40,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('forgotten_password_code', 'string', 40, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 40,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('remember_code', 'string', 40, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 40,
         'fixed' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('last_login', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'unsigned' => 1,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('active', 'integer', 1, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 1,
         'unsigned' => 1,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('groups_id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'unsigned' => 1,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
}

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
$this->hasOne('Groups', array(
         'local' => 'groups_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));
$this->hasOne('Profile', array(
        'local' => 'id',
        'foreign' => 'users_id'));
}
 }

 <?php
```

> /**
>    * BaseProfile
>    * 
>    * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
>    * 
>    * @property integer $id
>    * @property string $role
>    * @property string $first
>    * @property string $last
>    * @property string $email
>    * @property string $phone_1
>    * @property string $phone_2
>    * @property string $address
>    * @property string $postcode
>    * @property date $created_at
>    * @property date $updated_at
>    * @property Doctrine_Collection $Member
>    * @property Doctrine_Collection $Post
>    * @property Doctrine_Collection $ThreadHasProfile
>    * @property Doctrine_Collection $UserSetting
>    * 
>    * @package    ##PACKAGE##
>    * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
>    * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
>    * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 6401 2009-09-24 16:12:04Z guilhermeblanco $
>    */
>     abstract class BaseProfile extends Doctrine_Record
>        {
>       public function setTableDefinition()
>       {
>           $this->actAs("Timestampable");
>           $this->setTableName('profile');
>           $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
>                'type' => 'integer',
>                'length' => 4,
>                'unsigned' => 0,
>                'primary' => true,
>                'autoincrement' => true,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('users_id', 'integer', 4, array(
>                'type' => 'integer',
>                'length' => 4,
>                'unsigned' => 0,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                )); 
>           $this->hasColumn('role', 'string', null, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => true,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('first', 'string', 45, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'length' => 45,
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => true,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('last', 'string', 45, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'length' => 45,
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => true,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('phone_1', 'string', 45, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'length' => 45,
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => false,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('phone_2', 'string', 45, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'length' => 45,
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => false,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('address', 'string', 200, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'length' => 200,
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => false,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('postcode', 'string', 10, array(
>                'type' => 'string',
>                'length' => 10,
>                'fixed' => false,
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => false,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'date', null, array(
>                'type' => 'date',
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => true,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>           $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'date', null, array(
>                'type' => 'date',
>                'primary' => false,
>                'notnull' => true,
>                'autoincrement' => false,
>                ));
>       }

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
$this->hasMany('Member', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'profile_id'));

    $this->hasMany('Post', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'profile_id'));

    $this->hasMany('ThreadHasProfile', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'profile_id'));

    $this->hasMany('UserSetting', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'profile_id'));

    $this->hasOne('Users', array(
        'local' => 'users_id',
        'foreign' => 'id'));
}
```

}

Comment: can you provide your doctrine models (either in PHP or YAML) to help in answering the question

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to skin this cat.  I have created a simplified example based loosely on what I can gather from your question.

Firstly, here is the YAML that I use to generate for my one-to-one model classes:

```
Identity:
  columns:
    username: string(50)
    password: string(50)
    email: string(50)

Profile:
  columns:
    identity_id: integer(10)
    firstname: string(50)
    lastname: string(50)
  relations:
    Identity:
      foreignType: one
```

Now in PHP I can create a new Identity (or User in your case) and add related Profile data by simply:

```
        $identity = new Identity();
        $identity->username = 'james';
        $identity->password = 'secret';
        $identity->email = 'james@bond.com';
        //now adding the related data
        $identity->Profile->firstname = 'james';
        $identity->Profile->lastname = 'bond';
        $identity->save();
```

Hopefully this example will help you a bit.

**edit:**

here are the generated classes from the YAML in case that also helps:

BaseIdentity.php

```
<?php
abstract class BaseIdentity extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('identity');
        $this->hasColumn('username', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('email', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '50',
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Profile', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'identity_id'));
    }
}
```

BaseProfile.php

```
<?php

abstract class BaseProfile extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('profile');
        $this->hasColumn('identity_id', 'integer', 10, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => '10',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('firstname', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('lastname', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '50',
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Identity', array(
             'local' => 'identity_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It should.  I'll have to go through your code a bit closer and see what else is happening.  Could you pop up the YAML for your models? - it is a little easier to work through than the actual PHP generated classes

Comment: I'll have a go! I've never generated a YAML file before. Is there an easy way to do it? Also, I'm away from my computer at the mo, so there might be a delay!

Comment: I'm having permission problems when trying to convert my models to yaml with Doctrine. I'm assuming Doctrine will be trying to save the new file in the web root so I don't understand why it's not allowed to!

Answer (score 0):

Before `$p->save();`, have `$p->users_id = $u->id`.

Also, why are you calling the table User*s* (plural)? That's just going to make code very confusing.

Also again, if you have separate tables to hold different info about the user (a User and a user's Profile) because you saw it in sfGuardPlugin, PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS! It is a ridiculous idea that will only make you regret it later. I don't know what the Symfony/Doctrine team were drinking when they thought of that idea...

Comment: Kind of worked... The error disappeared, but the users_id column in the profile table has a value of 0 not the value of users.id. 
As for your other suggestions, the code is actually based on the ion_auth library for codeigniter. The table is called users cos I haven't got around to changing it. I've separated out the data to keep data needed for auth separate from general data about the user.

Comment: Isn't storing the profile in a separate table just basic database normalization? Why is it ridiculous?